# Frame of animated GIF only showing deltas

Tags: imagemagick, frame, animated-gif

I'm trying to grab the frames of an animated gif. I tried http://gif-explode.com and `convert +adjoin loading.gif out%d.gif` in ImageMagik. Unfortunately in both cases all but the first and last frame are kinda blurred and partially missing. I'm guessing the creator of the animated gif used some sort of compression where each "frame" is just a delta from the previous frame.

**How can I get useable frames from an animated gif like this?** Perhaps there's an option somewhere in ImageMagik or another piece of software that can do the reconstruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to specify “coalesce” and “dispose” options:

```
convert -coalesce +adjoin -dispose Previous loading.gif out%d.gif
```