# How can I convert a video into an image sequence with only the delta between frames?

Tags: image-processing, video-processing

I'm doing a bit of an experiment with showing low-framerate video in an HTML canvas, but I'd like to try to cut down the amount of data I'm transferring by only saving the delta for each frame. It's a drawing timelapse made from uncompressed PNG images, so the amount of information changing on each frame is fairly low, and I could possibly save a lot of space with some lossy PNG compression.

Any ideas where to start with something like this?

Comment: That sounds like an animated GIF to me.

Comment: That's exactly what it is, but with much more control over framerate and play/pause. In fact, it looks like ImageMagick exports delta by default, according to another question on here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317092/frame-of-animated-gif-only-showing-deltas

Comment: Do you want exactly one full frame (at the start) or will periodic full frame refreshes do?

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting idea and I would want to achieve that result too. Our issue is that we cannot play inline video on iPhone, so we use jpg sequence to emulate video mode. But it takes much of the bandwidth. Converting video into sequence of delta only would be a great improvement!

Answer (score 0):

May be relevant - I had to stream weather animations to the web and to cut down the data rate I overlayed two images - the background image was the start point, the foreground image transparent - subsequent foreground images contained only the difference. Controlled by Javascript, allowed speed and direction conmtrol. Advantage for me was the background image did not change, you would need to update the background image periodically.